# How to implement an autocomplete search field (suggestor) with an existing ElasticSearch index?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, vaadin

The ES index consists of 2 types that are implicitly mapped (default mapping). One type is "person" or an author, the 2nd type is "document".
The index has some 500k entries.
What I have to do is: implement an autocomplete (suggestions) functionality where only the fields "title", "classification" (document) and "name" (author) are relevant for the suggestions shown to the user.

Could it be done without changing the 500k docs in the index?
I found some tutorials that suggest preparing a specific mapping and also altering the documents (this I want to avoid if possible) and so on but I am new to this and I am not sure how to go about the this problem?
Below is the JSON for the index, and how the documents look:

```
//a Document
{
  "rawsource": "Phys.Rev. D67 (2003) 084031",
  "pubyear": 2003,
  "citedFrom": 19,
  "topics": [
    {
      "name": "General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology"
    }
  ],
  "cited": [
    {
      "ref": 0,
      "id": "PN132433"
    },
    {
      "ref": 1,
      "id": "PN206900"
    }
  ],
  "id": "PN120001",
  "collection": "PN",
  "source": "Phys Rev D",
  "classification": "Physics",
  "title": "Observables in causal set cosmology",
  "url": "http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0210061",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Brightwell, Graham"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dowker, H. Fay"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garcia, Raquel S."
    },
    {
      "name": "Henson, Joe"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sorkin, Rafael D."
    }
  ]
}

//a Person (author)

{
    "name": "Terasawa, M.",
    "documents": [
        {
            "citedFrom": 0,
            "id": "PN039187"
        }
    ],
    "coAuthors": [
        {
            "name": "Famiano, M. A.",
            "count": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Boyd, R. N.",
            "count": "1"
        }
    ],
    "topics": [
        {
            "name": "Astrophysics",
            "count": "1"
        }
    ]
}

//the mapping (implicit/default)

{
  "dlsnew": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "coAuthors": {
            "properties": {
              "count": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "documents": {
            "properties": {
              "citedFrom": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "referenced": {
            "properties": {
              "count": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "topics": {
            "properties": {
              "count": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "document": {
        "properties": {
          "abstract": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "authors": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "cited": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "ref": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "citedFrom": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "classification": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "collection": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "pubyear": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "rawsource": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "topics": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1454247029258",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "uuid": "k_CyQaxwSAaae67wW98HyQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "1050299"
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    },
    "warmers": {

    }
  }
}
```

The implementation is to be done using JAVA and the Vaadin Framework (this is not relevant at this point, but examples in Java/Vaadin will be most welcomed).
Thanks.

Comment: Which type of object will you output? Documents only or mixed (documents and authors in the same list)?

Comment: Both types (mixed), if possible, should look something like www.sowiport.de

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I solved my problem on the Elasticsearch side or at least to a good enough extend for me and the task at hand. I followed this [ruby example](https://gist.github.com/karmi/4526141#file-movie-titles-rb-L103).

I had to re-index all documents to accommodate the new settings for my index and to change my mapping explicitly.

They key is in defining proper analyzers and an edgeNGram filter in this case, like so:

```
"settings": {
     "index": {
        "analysis": {
           "filter": {
              "def_ngram_filter": {
                 "min_gram": "1",
                 "side": "front",
                 "type": "edgeNGram",
                 "max_gram": "16"
              }
           },
           "analyzer": {
              "def_search_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "def_tokenizer"
              },
              "def_ngram_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "def_ngram_filter"
                 ],
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "def_tokenizer"
              },
              "def_shingle_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "shingle",
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "def_tokenizer"
              },
              "def_default_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "def_tokenizer"
              }
           },
           "tokenizer": {
              "def_tokenizer": {
                 "type": "whitespace"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

and the use these in the mapping for the fields to be searched, like so:

```
"mappings": {
     "person": {
        "properties": {
           "coAuthors": {
              "properties": {
                 "count": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           },
           "documents": {
              "properties": {
                 "citedFrom": {
                    "type": "long"
                 },
                 "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           },
           "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "def_default_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                 "ngrams": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "def_ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "def_search_analyzer"
                 },
                 "shingles": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_shingle_analyzer"
                 },
                 "stemmed": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_snowball_analyzer"
                 }
              }
           },
           "referenced": {
              "properties": {
                 "count": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           },
           "topics": {
              "properties": {
                 "count": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     },
     "document": {
        "properties": {
           "abstract": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "authors": {
              "properties": {
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_default_analyzer",
                    "fields": {
                       "ngrams": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index_analyzer": "def_ngram_analyzer",
                          "search_analyzer": "def_search_analyzer"
                       },
                       "shingles": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "def_shingle_analyzer"
                       },
                       "stemmed": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "def_snowball_analyzer"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           "cited": {
              "properties": {
                 "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "ref": {
                    "type": "long"
                 }
              }
           },
           "citedFrom": {
              "type": "long"
           },
           "classification": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "collection": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "id": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "pubyear": {
              "type": "long"
           },
           "rawsource": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "source": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "def_default_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                 "ngrams": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "def_ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "def_search_analyzer"
                 },
                 "shingles": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_shingle_analyzer"
                 },
                 "stemmed": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_snowball_analyzer"
                 }
              }
           },
           "topics": {
              "properties": {
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "def_default_analyzer",
                    "fields": {
                       "ngrams": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index_analyzer": "def_ngram_analyzer",
                          "search_analyzer": "def_search_analyzer"
                       },
                       "shingles": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "def_shingle_analyzer"
                       },
                       "stemmed": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "def_snowball_analyzer"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           "url": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

then querying the index with the following works as expected:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_search  " -d'
{
   "size": 5,
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "physics",
         "type": "most_fields",
         "fields": [
             "document.title^10",
             "document.title.shingles^2",
             "document.title.ngrams",
             "person.name^10",
             "person.name.shingles^2",
             "person.name.ngrams",
             "document.topics.name^10",
             "document.topics.name.shingles^2",
             "document.topics.name.ngrams"
          ],
          "operator": "and"
      }
   }
}'
```

Hope this will help someone, it is probably not the best example as I am a complete noob to this, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

There exist different Autocomplete components for Vaadin.
Have a look at [this](https://vaadin.com/directory#!browse/vaadin=7/search=autocomplete) link.

Depending on which Add-On you choose, the databinding is done differently, but you have to "connect" it to your index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about the existing addons. This is more of an elasticsearch issue at this point since the vaadin componets expect the information to be alredy available in order to be able to propose the suggestions.